# Fetch data from multiple coloumns in simgle table PHP & SQL

Tags: mysql

i have a table and 5 coloumns with some values similar to each other coloumn. Now i want to get all data from these coloumns in html select field.![enter image description here][1]

```
SELECT CONCAT (chemical_entity_0, chemical_entity_1, chemical_entity_2, chemical_entity_3, chemical_entity_4, chemical_entity_5, chemical_entity_6, chemical_entity_7, chemical_entity_8, chemical_entity_9) AS chemical_entity 
FROM msds
```

Comment: My code is SELECT CONCAT (chemical_entity_0, chemical_entity_1, chemical_entity_2, chemical_entity_3, chemical_entity_4, chemical_entity_5, chemical_entity_6, chemical_entity_7, chemical_entity_8, chemical_entity_9) AS chemical_entity FROM msds

Comment: But i get all cols data in single line.. but i want them in next line

Comment: That really comes down to formatting, which will depend on how you are presenting them. You have rolled all the columns into a single field. Do you want to bring back multiple rows, or a single row with a carriage return between each value?

Comment: i want a return each filed in next line not all cols attach as concat do

Answer (score 0):

If you want a row per column then use UNION:-

```
SELECT chemical_entity_1 AS chemical_entity 
FROM msds
UNION ALL
SELECT chemical_entity_2 AS chemical_entity 
FROM msds
UNION ALL
SELECT chemical_entity_3 AS chemical_entity 
FROM msds
UNION ALL
SELECT chemical_entity_4 AS chemical_entity 
FROM msds
UNION ALL
SELECT chemical_entity_5 AS chemical_entity 
FROM msds
UNION ALL
SELECT chemical_entity_6 AS chemical_entity 
FROM msds
UNION ALL
SELECT chemical_entity_7 AS chemical_entity 
FROM msds
UNION ALL
SELECT chemical_entity_8 AS chemical_entity 
FROM msds
UNION ALL
SELECT chemical_entity_9 AS chemical_entity 
FROM msds
```